# React JS set array object value

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object

Totally loss although this must be simple?

To this json 'client'.

I am trying to set capacities[0].value to a value from input but fail.

Thanks!

`[ { "Timezone": "VN", "Id": "9682334", "email": "booking@test.vn", "capacities": [ { "name": "capacity", "value": 360 }, { "name": "seats", "value": 560 }, ], } ]`

`onChange={(e) => setClient({...client, capacities[0].value: e.target.value })};`

Comment: Hey! I guess you didn't access the variable correctly to1 set a new value. Example:

For `const array = [ { "Timezone": "VN", "Id": "9682334", "email": "booking@test.vn", "capacities": [ { "name": "capacity", "value": 360 }, { "name": "seats", "value": 560 }, ], } ]`, use `array[0].capacities[0].value` to access the key correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be an array but in the `setClient`, you are destructuring an object called client. This needs to be fixed first.

Assuming we do that and get an object like that:

```
const jsonObj = {
    data: {
      Timezone: 'VN',
      Id: '9682334',
      email: 'booking@test.vn',
      capacities: [
        { name: 'capacity', value: 360 },
        { name: 'seats', value: 560 },
      ],
    },
  };
```

and set the state like this:

```
const [client, setClient] = useState(jsonObj);
```

Then what you want to do can be done this way:

```
(e) => {
    client.data.capacities[0].value = e.target.value;
    setClient({ ...client });
  };
```

The reason your approach is not working is that in JS the key value of an object can be either a string or a symbol.